# "Cannot be pasted to [the] cells that are editable"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

> - … cannot be pasted to the cells that are editable.
> - … cannot be pasted to cells that are editable.

Intuitively, I am inclined to think that second fragment is correct. The rule is generically applicable all types of cells and there is no context to the type of cells other than what is stated in sentence. Am I correct?

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "* cannot be pasted to the cells that are editable" or "* **cannot be pasted to cells that are editable**".

The second choice is acceptable. Also, "* cannot be pasted to editable cells" is more natural.

On the subject of article usage:

> Intuitively, I am inclined to think that **the** second sentence is correct. The rule is generically applicable **to** all types of cells and there is no context to the type of cells other than what is stated in **the** sentence. Am I correct?